# updating multiple items through checkbox in php

Tags: php

can any tell me how to update multiple checkbox values in database. i am using the following code.

```
<form method="post" action="update.php"> 
<select name="stat">
<option value="">Move To</option>
  <option value="shortlisted">Shortlisted</option>
    <option value="finalised">Finalised</option>
<option value="rejected">Rejected</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Add"/>
<input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $j_id ;?>">
<input  name="cid[]" value="<? echo $cid ; ?> " type="hidden"/>
```

in php update.php

```
$job_id = $_POST["checkbox"];
$cand_id = $_POST["cid"];
$resume_status = trim($_POST["stat"]);
foreach ($job_id as $id ) {
$sql="UPDATE job_apply SET stat ='$resume_status' WHERE jid='$id' AND cid='$cid'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

when the user select multiple checkboxes only one column is getting updated.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Comment: where are the multiple checkboxes? I see only one

Comment: its for multiple database results. it cant display the database results